# CATransaction synchronize called within transaction

Tags: ios, swift, crash, xcode8

My app was working fine, displaying lines from an HTML file in a UITableView, but after updating some PODs the app crashes during startup and I receive this error and XCode doesn't show the exact line or function in which this error happens:

```
[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
```

The only thing I updated is HTMLKit.

Comment: Try adding a symbolic breakpoint at +[CATransaction synchronize] to analyze the stacktrace when the error occurs.